# Meteor google map maxZoom, minZoom and zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor, google-maps-api-3, meteor-blaze

I am using a meteor [google map package](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps) and I would like to restraint the map zoom level (because I am doing a [Geospatial Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#spherical)).
Normaly it should be done in my mapOptions.
My code looks like this:
On my template I have my map

```
<template name="mypage">
    <div class="map-container">
      {{> googleMap name="map" options=mapOptions}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Then on my Javascript helper I should have my map options like this:

```
Template.mypage.helpers({
  mapOptions: function(){
    if(GoogleMaps.loaded()){
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.8520442,2.3346246),
        zoom: 13,
        maxZoom: 15
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Unfortunately the maxZoom seems to not work...
Are they any other possibilities to restraint the zoom ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the solution, 
A maxZoom and a minZoom have to be declared in other to have the zoom level control.
So a possible solution can look like this:

```
Template.mypage.helpers({
  mapOptions: function(){
    if(GoogleMaps.loaded()){
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.8520442,2.3346246),
        zoom: 13,
        maxZoom: 20,
        minZoom: 13
      }
    }
  }
})
```